# how to bind dynamic value for ngclass in angular material?

Tags: typescript, sass

[I want to bind the 0th index of splitted value to the ngclass. 
And i can't do that in backend. I have to do it in .html itself. any help?

In .ts file

```
 response = "success&2018-12-19 09:26:03";
    this.status = response;
```

in .html page

```
<div  ngClass="row.status.split['&'][0]">{{row.status.split['&'][1]}}</div>
```

in .scss file

```
.success {
     background-color: #4A993A;
     height:25px; width:200px;
     border-radius:4px;
     color: white;
     margin-right: 9px;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top:3px;
}
```

I am not getting how to give correct syntax for ngclass for dynamic splitted value.

Comment: Can you provide sample code? It will be easy for us to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should make sure  `response = "success&2018-12-19 09:26:03";`
is not null. If it's null handle it. and by given code i tried to understand and giving my solution here. Not sure whether it helps, since i don't have sample code to reproduce the issue. Replace that line of code with this.

```
<div [ngClass]="row.status.split('&')[0]">{{row.status.split('&')[1]}}</div>
```